# flake8 & pycodestyle/pep8 not showing E721 errors

Tags: python, pep8, flake8, pycodestyle

###### Versions

```bash
λ python --version
Python 3.10.6

λ flake8 --version
5.0.4 (mccabe: 0.7.0, pycodestyle: 2.9.1, pyflakes: 2.5.0) CPython 3.10.6 on Linux 
# and on Windows

## Edit: after update
λ flake8 --version
6.0.0 (mccabe: 0.7.0, pycodestyle: 2.10.0, pyflakes: 3.0.1) CPython 3.10.6 on Linux
```

###### Error to Catch

- https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E721.html

  - **No:** `type(user) == User`
  - **Do:** `isinstance(user, User)`

###### Example *(test.py)*

```py
test = []
if type(test) == list:
    print('test is a list')
else:
    print('test not a list')
```

Both `flake8 test.py` & `pycodestyle test.py` commands, in terminal, do not show any errors. Yet they should.
I have no extra config, from what I'm reading this error should be enabled by default; Per [pycodestyle 2.9.1 Docs](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/2.9.1/intro.html#error-codes)

- unless disabled per line with `# noqa`

I've also tried:

- `{flake8|pycodestyle} --select E721 test.py` to explicitly select the error
- `{flake8|pycodestyle} --ignore E302 test.py` to clear the default ignore list
- `{flake8|pycodestyle} --ignore E302 --select E721 test.py`

Am I missing something?- I quite like this error and now I'm worried it's not catching **other** errors as well.

Comment: stackoverflow isn't the appropriate place for bug reports -- please search the pycodestyle issue tracker for duplicates -- also you're on an old version

Comment: @anthonysottile okay! will do!- I wasn't sure if it was some sort of setting or, yeah, just an old version. I guess I'll figure out how to update it, I just pip'd it, and if that doesn't work check the bug tracker. ty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help somebody in the future.

This is proper behavior, the Docs do not correctly describe the error

##### Per this comment in the source code:

```
# Allow comparison for types which are not obvious
```

- Location: pycodestyle.py, comparison_type(), line 1436 in version 2.10.0

##### `obvious` types are:

```
SINGLETONS = frozenset(['False', 'None', 'True'])
```

- Location: pycodestyle.py, line 104 in version 2.10.0

Their Doc example of `if type(user) == User:` is not obvious and therefor wouldn't trigger it

##### Examples

```py
test = []
print(type(test) == list)         # Pass
print(type(test) == type(list))   # Pass
print(type(test) == type(float))  # Pass
print(type(test) == type(None))   # Fail
print(type(test) == type(True))   # Fail
```

I presume **some** Linters, possible pylint, does not work like this- thus my confusion, as I saw this error while using pylsp-all in Vim